# Declaring and initializing static objects at class scope

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, it is common for a class to keep a static reference to an instance that the class will use several times. For example,

```
@implementation MyClass

static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;

+ (void) initialize {
    if (self == [MyClass class]) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
}

@end
```

In Swift we no longer have to declare and initialize this static object in two different places. We can simply do

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
```

at class scope and the date formatter is initialized when the class is loaded.

My question: when writing in Swift, is there any reason *not* to use this new pattern? It would still be possible to declare the date formatter at module scope and then initialize it within `initialize`; is there any reason to do it in two steps like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no such reason; the self-initializing variable is the way to go.

Even better, self-initialize it to a called closure and the date formatter can be further initialized / configured, right there.

Not only that, but if you mark it as `@lazy` then it won't even be initialized until the first time you actually access it.

Comment: And if one declares the variable (with var) in global scope, you get the "lazy" thing for free, as mentioned in Apple's doc (« Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike lazy stored properties, global constants and variables do not need to be marked with the lazy attribute.)

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan Correct-a-mundo. I mention `@lazy` only because he proposed to put this var at the top level of the class, not at the top level of the file - and I think he is right to do so.